# Use JSON.parse to parse OpenStruct or a hash

Tags: json, ruby, hashmap, openstruct

I tried to parse a simple JSON like that:

```
JSON.parse({"pong": "ok"})
```

and it failed

```
2.4.0 :014 > JSON.parse({"pong": "ok"})
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
    from (irb):14
```

What's wrong here ? Why should I convert to String ?

Another try, with **OpenStruct** this time:

```
2.4.0 :001 > pong = OpenStruct.new(pong: 'OK')
 => #<OpenStruct pong="OK"> 
2.4.0 :002 > JSON.parse(pong)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of OpenStruct into String
    from (irb):2
```

The same ?
Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to generate a JSON **string** from a ruby hash, then you can `require 'json'`, then use `Hash#to_json`

Comment: I'm trying to return some JSON response from a dummy Ping controller (Rails 5, Ruby 2.5.0) as follows: `render json: <some object>`. That's why I tried without success to pass in a JSON or an OpenStruct object: `OpenStruct.new(pong: 'OK')`.

Comment: `render json: {pong: 'ok'}` should work??

Comment: By the way, your console above shows ruby `2.4.0`, not `2.5.0`.

Comment: @TomLord, nice catch, I updated `Gemfile`5 sec later to use 2.5.0. Yep, thanks you, your version worked for me.

Comment: If you're updating the ruby version now, then - unless you have a good reason not to - you should use the latest version: `2.5.1`.

Answer (score 7):

[`JSON.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) parses `json` and `json` means `String`:

```
JSON.parse('{"pong": "ok"}')
#⇒ {"pong"=>"ok"}
```

Also, you might *parse* json string into `OpenStruct`:

```
JSON.parse('{"pong":"ok"}', object_class: OpenStruct).pong
#⇒ "ok"
```

Comment: thank you, the 1st solution worked for me (my bad, I had to pass in a String as you did and not a Hash)